# Actual and formal arguments differ in length - Java Constructor Error

Tags: java

This is a simulator in which the population of Birds changes on a turn basis depending on different natural occurrences such as food, breeding, etc. I am using an ArrayList to store the Doves.

I'm not entirely sure what is wrong with my code here but the compiler error is 'actual and formal arguments differ in length'. If someone could give pointers into the right direction that would be appreciated.

Super class

```
public abstract class Bird
{

protected int age;

public Bird(int age)
{
age = 0; 
}
}
```

Sub class

```
public class Dove extends Bird
{
private static final int BREEDING_AGE = 2;
private static final int MAX_AGE = 15;
private static final double EGG_PROBABILITY = 0.16;
private static final int MAX_NEST_SIZE = 2;
private static final Random rand = Randomizer.getRandom();

private boolean alive;
private Location location;
private Field field;

public Dove(int age, boolean randomAge, Field field, Location location)
{
    super(age);
    alive = true;
    this.field = field;
    setLocation(location);
    if(randomAge) {
        age = rand.nextInt(MAX_AGE);
    }
}

private boolean willBreed()
{
    return age >= BREEDING_AGE;
}

public void increaseAge()
{
    age++;
    if(age > MAX_AGE) {
        setDead();
    }
}

public void run(List<Dove> newDoves)
{
    increaseAge();
    if(alive) {
        giveBirth(newDoves);            
        Location newLocation = field.freeAdjacentLocation(location);
        if(newLocation != null) {
            setLocation(newLocation);
        }
        else {
            // Overcrowding.
            setDead();
        }
    }
}

public boolean stillAlive()
{
    return alive;
}

public void killBird()
{
    alive = false;
    if(location != null) {
        field.clear(location);
        location = null;
        field = null;
    }
}

public Location getLocation()
{
    return location;
}

private void setLocation(Location newLocation)
{
    if(location != null) {
        field.clear(location);
    }
    location = newLocation;
    field.place(this, newLocation);
}

private void giveBirth(List<Dove> Dove)
{
    List<Location> free = field.getFreeAdjacentLocations(location);
    int births = breed();
    for(int b = 0; b < births && free.size() > 0; b++) {
        Location loc = free.remove(0);
        Dove chick = new Dove(false, field, loc);
        newDoves.add(chick);
    }
}

private int breed()
{
    int births = 0;
    if(canBreed() && rand.nextDouble() <= EGG_PROBABILITY) {
        births = rand.nextInt(MAX_NEST_SIZE) + 1;
    }
    return births;
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your `Dove` constructor has **4** parameter, but you only pass **3** arguments. Of course this will fail.

Comment: What do you mean, I have arguments for all 4 parameters as int age is covered in the class Bird constructor?

Comment: `new`is a keyword in Java. you can not use it as variable Name.

Comment: Oh, thanks, changed it but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the signature of your constructor:

```
public Dove(int age, boolean randomAge, Field field, Location location)
```

This is how you try to instantiate a `Dove` object:

```
Dove chick = new Dove(false, field, loc);
```

<sub>(Previously you named your variable `new` which was wrong, but I see you edited it so I won't reference this)</sub>
You are passing **3** arguments to the constructor, when as you see it takes **4**.

To fix this just add an `age` parameter to the call, possibly like so:

```
Dove chick = new Dove(10, false, field, loc);
```

The above will create a `Dove` with `age = 10`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see now. Thanks.

Comment: @Coder314 please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer if you found it helpful.